# How to give (100% - 40px) height to background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image with `background-attachment: fixed`. I want to set it's height 40px less than the height of the viewport. Setting `background-size: 100%` sets the height equal to viewport's height. But `background-size: 100%  calc(100% - 40px);` doesn't do anything.

The background is actually given to carousel's images in a bootstrap website. The image to which background-image is given has classes `.items.active`. I am also looking for javascript fallback for those browser which do not allow `calc()` function. I do not know very much javascript. I tried the folloeing jquery code:

```
$(".item.active").css('background-size', '100% 100%').css('background-size', '-=100px -=100px');
```

But it also doesn't work. I tried simple javascript as far as I know as:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".item.active")[0].style.background-size = "100% calc(100%-40px)";
```

But that also doesn't work.

Comment: Why `background-size: 100% - calc(100% - 40px);` and not `background-size: 100% calc(100% - 40px);`? I think you have a typo, it should work otherwise. The calc will subtract 40px from 100%.

Comment: `style.background-size` - Again, error. It should be `.style.backgroundSize`.

Comment: @Harry Yeah that is a typo. I used `background-size: 100% calc(100% - 40px);` but it didn't work.

Comment: Show us your actual code then @user31782.

Comment: @Harry It is working now.

Comment: @Harry you should post the answer instead :D

Comment: @DanishAdeel: Normally I would have but I see this more as a typo error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should work. Just remove a "minus" in your code between width and height.

```
background-size: 100% calc(100% - 40px);
```

In javaScript there is a typo:
should be

> style.backgroundSize

instead of

> style.background-size

Comment: Ah yes, it is working now. Could you also tell javascript fallback for `calc()` function.

Comment: THere's another typo. It should be `document.getElementsByClassName("item active")[0].`

Comment: @user31782 try this one `document.getElementsByClassName("item active")[0].style.backgroundSize = "100% calc(100%-40px)";` there was a typo in your JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Use css calc https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

```
.item.active {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: But this would change the width of the `div`. Did you read my question? The `div` I am using has already appropriate width and height. And moreover changing `div`;s dimensions won't change `background-image`'s dimensions.

Comment: Set padding or margin left and right or use width: 90%;

Comment: Setting padding and margin don't affect fixed background image's dimensions. '-1'.

Comment: its not about width.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
var width = $(".item.active").width();//get the width
var height = $(".item.active").height();//get the height

$(".item.active").css('background-size', (width-100)+'px '+(height-100)+'px');//change the size of the background
```

note: you background need to be center in the middle of the div